# when compiling a program with g++, using old phantom version of current file

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I'm tearing my hair out over this issue.

I've got a .h file that starts with #ifndef and #define, like normal.  When I first compiled it, I had a typo so it was accidentally written like this:  #ifnef  .  I fixed it, saved the file, recompiled, but the g++ compiler is still giving me the same issue, the preprocessor doesn't know how to read "#ifnef".

```
error: invalid preprocessing directive #ifnef
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  I've changed the file, there are no copies of the file with the typo hanging around, no object files hanging around.

I'm using this makefile:

```
# Declaration of variables
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -w -I.

# File names
EXEC = run
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

# Main target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

# To obtain object files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

# To remove generated files
clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

then, this is my .h file:

```
#include "UDP-base.h"
#include <queue>

#ifndef STREAM_MANAGER_H
#define STREAM_MANAGER_H

/*Stuff here*/

#endif // STREAM_MANAGER_H
```

Comment: `ccache -C` perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm using a pretty much vanilla out-of-the-box ubuntu 15 virtual machine.  It doesn't say I have any compiler cache installed.

Comment: Edit:  It seems that once I open a terminal, it refuses to acknowledge any changes to files until I close it and open it again.  Solved the problem, mostly, but I would prefer if there was a way to make this...you know...not happen.  I like being able to move over to a terminal window and type "make", instead of having to open terminal, navigate to the files, and make it every time.

Comment: What editor are you using, that can't modify files until you close the terminal?